# editing sharepoint file in the feature folder

Tags: feature, recommendations

I'm having an issue. I want to make a quick change to an aspx file that I recently deployed to a sharepoint server. Due to some circumstances, it is not worth the time to edit and recompile the project and redeploy.

The issue is that, i edit the aspx file in the templates\feature\mpcalendar folder (where mpcalendar is my project). the file name is mpcalendar.aspx

the aspx file has some javascript lines which i want to comment out.

i tried editing the file, but the sharepoint is not showing the changes. the file is edited and saved, but the sharepoint is loading the old file. if i just retract the solution, the files from that folder are gone and redeploy, the files appear again.

if i try to edit again after the deploy, it still does not reflect the change.

is it being cached somewhere? i could not find any other instance of this file "mpcalendar.asp" in the whole drive except here.. (templates\feature\mpcalendar\mpcalendar.aspx"

please help figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if the file is Unghosted. What does your Elements.xml file look? If you don't set the Type attribute (in the `<File>` element) to Ghostable or GhostableInLibrary, the file will be Unghosted and therefore stored in the database and not at in the file system.

You can read more about Ghosting and Unghosting here: http://www.davidyardy.com/blog/post/2010/09/15/SharePointe28093-Ghostable-and-GhostableInLibrary.aspx

Answer (score 0):

have you tried performing an iisreset?

Start - cmd - iisreset

Answer (score -1):

SharePoint does not read from templates\feature folder at runtime.
Find out which document  library the file is being uploaded to during feature activation. You can get this from the *Module* element in the *elements.xml* file.
Then download the file from that document library, edit it and upload it again replacing the original with new version.